# Python Windows Resource Monitoring

Tags: python, windows

I was looking to monitor processor usage, memory usage, disk I/O, network interface usage, using Python in Windows. Is this possible? Does there exist some sort of API in Windows to allow me access to that information or perhaps a module? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WMI](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) module might be an interesting option for you. It may be an overkill, but it does look like a very standard and reliable way of querying the state of a Windows machine. Check out [WMI Cookbook](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html)

Comment: WMI looks right inline with what I needed, I elected however for the psutils module here - https://code.google.com/p/psutil/ Thanks for your input @Danish !